# Most efficient on main thread method to go save drawing from canvas to disk

Tags: firefox-addon

I have a drawing on a canvas and I want to save it to disk.

I have two approaches currently:

#### Method 1

1. canvas.toBlob
2. nsIDOMFileReader.readAsArrayBuffer
3. Uint8Array(reader.result)
4. OS.File.writeAtomic

can copy paste and run from scratchpad, it will place savedImage.png on desktop:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'canvas');
    canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        console.time('sta');
    (canvas.toBlobHD || canvas.toBlob).call(canvas, function(b) {
        var r = Cc['@mozilla.org/files/filereader;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIDOMFileReader); //new FileReader();
        r.onloadend = function() {
            // r.result contains the ArrayBuffer.
            var writePath = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir, 'savedImage.png');
                    console.log('r.result:', r.result);
            var promise = OS.File.writeAtomic(writePath, new Uint8Array(r.result), { tmpPath: writePath + '.tmp' });
            promise.then(
                function(aVal) {
                    console.log('successfully saved image to disk');
                                        console.timeEnd('sta');
                },
                function(aReason) {
                    console.log('writeAtomic failed for reason:', aReason);
                }
            );
        };
        r.readAsArrayBuffer(b);
    }, 'image/png');
};
//var path = OS.Path.toFileURI(OS.Path.join(OS.Contants.Path.desktopDir, 'my.png')); //do it like this for images on disk
var path = 'https://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/firefox/channel/toggler-beta.png?2013-06'; //do like this for images online
img.src = path;
```

#### Method 2 (i couldnt get this to work)

1. canvas.getImageData (this function is not async? is it a burden on main thread?)
2. Uint8Array(ImageData.data.buffer)
3. OS.File.writeAtomic

snippet i was trying to get to work for method 2, the file kept saying it was corrupt:

can copy paste this and run it, it will make a filed called savedImage.png on your desktop, but it will be corrupt

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'canvas');
    canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        console.time('sta');
        var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        console.log('imgData:', imgData.data, new Uint8Array(imgData.data.buffer));
        var writePath = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir, 'savedImage.png');
            var promise = OS.File.writeAtomic(writePath, new Uint8Array(imgData.data.buffer), { tmpPath: writePath + '.tmp' });
            promise.then(
                function(aVal) {
                    console.log('successfully saved image to disk');
                                        console.timeEnd('sta');
                },
                function(aReason) {
                    console.log('writeAtomic failed for reason:', aReason);
                }
            );
};
//var path = OS.Path.toFileURI(OS.Path.join(OS.Contants.Path.desktopDir, 'my.png')); //do it like this for images on disk
var path = 'https://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/firefox/channel/toggler-beta.png?2013-06'; //do like this for images online
img.src = path;
```

Comment: `getImageData` does not encode the image data, you have to do that yourself.

Comment: Thanks @paa would the `getImageData` be better then the `toBlob` if I encoded it? Like lighter on the main thread?

Answer (score 2):

Method 1 looks right to me, so I'll analyze that

### Async

`canvas.toBlob`, as per [mozilla bug 817700](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=817700) this is async.

`FileReader` uses callbacks, so presumbly async

`new Uint8Array(ArrayBuffer)` just provides a view on an already existing buffer, it's more or less constant-time operation

`OS.File` is designed to be async, returns promises

### Sync (maybe)

`ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)`, the API does not indicate that calls to drawImage can be deferred.
Although in principle an off-screen canvas could be treated as one huge, stateful promise. I don't know how it's implemented.

You might be able to speed it up by specifying the [canvas rendering context parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext#Parameters) `willReadFrequently`, which is a hint for firefox to create a software-rendered canvas which should avoid uploading the image texture to the gfx card.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this input man! Espeically that link showing that toBlob is happening off main thread!! edit: wait it looks like they backed out the fix, is that true?

Comment: backed out and checked in again

Answer (score 1):

Javascript example:

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d', {willReadFrequently: true});
```

Source:
https://github.com/fserb/canvas2D/blob/master/spec/will-read-frequently.md

Comment: Wow that's super cool! I didn't know about that!